# Zero gradient on the boundary

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function. Assume that $\langle (a,b),\nabla f(a,b) \rangle = 0$ for all $(a,b)$ on the boundary of the unit circle $D = \{x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$.

I want to show that there is a point on the boundary of $D$ where $\nabla f = \mathbf{0}$. How can I do it?

---

Edit: I think I solved it. Define $g \colon [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(\theta) = f(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. Note that $g \in C^1$, $g(0) = g(2\pi) = f(1,0)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(g) = \partial D$. By the chain rule,
$$ g'(\theta) = \nabla f(\cos\theta,\sin\theta) \cdot (-\sin\theta,\cos\theta). $$
By Rolle's theorem, there exists some $t \in (0,2\pi)$ where $g'(t) = 0$. Denote $\nabla f(\cos t,\sin t) = (\alpha,\beta)$. Then
$$\begin{cases}
\langle (\alpha,\beta), (\cos t,\sin t) \rangle = 0 \\
\langle (\alpha,\beta), (-\sin t,\cos t) \rangle = 0
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow $$
$$ \begin{cases}
\alpha \cos t + \beta \sin t = 0 \\
-\alpha \sin t + \beta \cos t = 0
\end{cases} \Rightarrow$$
$$ \begin{cases}
\alpha \sin t \cos t + \beta \sin^2 t = 0 \\
-\alpha \sin t \cos t + \beta \cos^2 t = 0
\end{cases} $$
and
$$ \beta = \beta(\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t) = 0. $$
Hence $\alpha \cos t = 0$ and $\alpha \sin t = 0$, and since $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ can't be zero for the same $t$, $\alpha = 0$. Then $\nabla f = \mathbf{0}$ at $(\cos t,\sin t) \in \partial D$.

Comment: Informally speaking, at any point on the circle the gradient is directed along the circle, and it can't climb always up or always down, because when you go all the way around the circle, you must arrive to the point where you started. Someplace along the way, the gradient must change from "up" to "down", and in doing so, pass through $0$.

Comment: Thanks, @IvanNeretin! I added my solution to the question. Your answer helped me a lot to get an idea how to solve it.